# My 'mysql-connector-java' version FIXED to 8.0.15

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, dependencies

I'm making project with springboot 2.

And want to make `my common library` module.

So I maked `common` and `Module A` modules.

I wanted to use `mysql-connector-java:5.1.40`, so I set in my `common` module's build.gradle dependency.

But when I import `common` to `Module A`, `Module A` has `mysql-connector-java:8.0.15`

my build.gradle files like this.

`springBootVersion` : 2.1.4.RELEASE

`common`'s build.gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")

    compile("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:${springKafkaVersion}")

    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.2.0'

    compile group: 'org.apache.curator', name: 'curator-recipes', version: '4.2.0'

    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.40')
}
```

`Module A`'s build.gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":common")
}
```

I don't know why version changed.

Is any library have `mysql-connector-java:8.0.15` in my used??

Comment: You can use maven show dependency tree to figure out which dependency is bringing that version: `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: I suspect it is Spring Boot's dependency management that is setting the version to 8.0.15. Can you show the rest of module A's `build.gradle`?

Comment: You can check the dependency tree for module-A, calling `gradle :ModuleA:dependencies`. Most likely, a spring project is bumping the version- and in Gradle, the higher version "wins" (unless configured otherwise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved.

Mayby it was intellij's bug......

I tried fixing build.gradle, cleaning IntelliJ cache.... etc.. But not resolved in my pc.

In other's pc, my build.gradle works great :(

So, I try re-installing IntelliJ and resolve my problem.

Thank you all for answering......